# QSORT on array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

If I have an array like this:

```
2, 4, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

1. Is there a way I can use qsort by sorting just the first 3 elements, and leaving the rest untouched?
2. Would `qsort(arrNumbers, 3, sizeof(int), compare)` do the job?
3. Does specifying the number of elements lower than the full array cause only that number of elements to become sorted?

EDIT:
My compare function is:

```
int comp(const int * a, const int * b)
   if(a==b)
   {
       return 0;
   }
   else
   {
      if(a<b)
      {
         return -1;
       }
       else
       {
         return 1;
       }
    }
```

Does it seem right?

Comment: Here's a novel idea: put it in a C program and see what happens!

Comment: what does [the manpage](http://www.opengroup.org/sud/sud1/xsh/qsort.htm) say?

Comment: Have you tried it? It should work, and it's not hard to try.

Comment: To the empiricists: the trouble is that trying does not prove anything if you take possible UB into account. Any 'evidence' could be coincidental. I'd say the standards documentation is a bit stronger

Comment: Just trying it is not enough. Its a sign that *maybe* it worked by design, maybe there was *undefined behavior* anywhere that coincidentally caused the program to output the expected answer, and maybe something else. So it's good to know the background, especially when working with C or C++.

Answer (score 7):

Yes.

Yes.<sup>*</sup>

Yes.

---

<sub>* Assuming you define `compare()` appropriately.</sub>

Comment: that's a great (sick) caveat!

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try it and see that it works as you expect?

Explanation: the `qsort` function only gets a *pointer* to the array, which does not say how long the array is. That's why you have to pass the size as well. In your function call you claim that the array is three `int`s long, and that's all the `qsort` function can be sure of. It will not access anything beyond that limit.

Answer (score 2):

The full signature is:

```
void qsort(
   void * base,
   size_t num,
   size_t width,
   int (__cdecl *compare )(const void *, const void *) 
);
```

To sort a specific *contiguous* range of the array, you just pass in a different `base` (pointer to starting element for the range) and `num` (number of elements in the range).

Answer (score 1):

Yes if you specify 3 in your case it will only sort the first 3 elements.